# Where is edit button on github?

Tags: github

I am following one tutorial

```
Click the "Edit" button on this file on GitHub:
```

https://github.com/lampepfl/progfun-wiki/blob/gh-pages/CheatSheet.md

But where is edit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's here

[image]

This will fork the project to your own repository. You can then edit, and submit a pull request.